# Positioned element adding to total div height

Tags: css

I have a 800 x 600 rotatable image with forward and back buttons repositioned to the sides.  The height of the div is suppose to be 600px, but the actual height of the div was pushed to 690, including the height of the button image.  And the div was blocking a row of clickable menu on top.  So I made the div height to 518px and moved top -75px to get the real dimension I want.  But I feel dirty doing this...  Is there a correct way to do this?  Or is this workaround more or less correct?  Below is the code.  Thanks!

```
<div class="Content Wide" id="LayoutColumn1">
     <div style=" width: 980px; height: 518px; display: block; position: relative; float: left;">
          <a href="#" onClick="prev();"><img src="/template/img/next_button.png" style="position: relative; top: 200px; left: 5px; z-index: 2;"></a>
          <a href="/chef-special/" id="mainLink"><img src="/template/img/chef_special_large.png" id="main" style="margin: 0 0 0 50px; position: relative; float: left; top: -75px; z-index: 1;"></a>
          <a href="#" onClick="next();"><img src="/template/img/next_button.png" style="position: relative; top: 200px; left: 787px; z-index: 2;"></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your next/previous buttons to affect the flow of other content, you should use position:absolute inside a container with position:relative.